# How to display in <div id="secound-item"> and my secound object and in third-item my third object?

Tags: django

```
text = MyText.objects.all()
```

in template:

```
{% for t in text %}

<div id="first-item">
    <h4>{{ t.name }}</h4>
</div>

<div id="secound-item">
    <h2> {{ t.name }} </h2>
</div>

<div id="third-item">
    <h1> {{ t.name }} </h1>
</div>
.....
{% endfor %}
```

How to display in `<div id="secound-item">` my secound object and in `third-item` my third object? et cetera...

Something like this will be optimal?

```
{% for t in text %}

<div id="first-item">
    <h4>{{ t.0.name }}</h4>
</div>

<div id="secound-item">
    <h2> {{ t.1.name }} </h2>
</div>

<div id="third-item">
    <h1> {{ t.2.name }} </h1>
</div>
.....
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [apnumber](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/humanize/#apnumber) filter from `django.contrib.humanize`, but that will only create words from numbers until 10. It will give you:

1 = one

2 = two

3 = three

But to get an ordinal like "first", "second", "third", you would have to write a [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/). IDs and classes in HTML can't start with an integer, but they can certainly have an integer in them. An easy solution to what I think you're trying to do is to simply reverse your values:

item-1

item-2

item-3

So you can just leverage the loop index. Also, you should limit your page to one `<h1>` tag which is about 90% the same as your title for SEO purposes.

If you're just wanting to include the index of the loop in the class name or id, I would do:

```
{% for t in text %}
<div id="item-{{ forloop.counter }}">
    <h4>{{ t.name }}</h4>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Classes and IDs of HTML elements can't start with an integer.

Comment: Sorry Brandon. My question was not clear. Please look at updated question.

Comment: You should re-phrase your question title.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for t in text %}

<div id="{{t.id}}-item">
    <h4>{{ t.name }}</h4>
</div>

{% endfor %}
```